# Plotting discrete 3D vector field with quiver and meshgrid

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot an electric vector field that takes in user-inputted wire geometry, and outputs a 3D field on a 3D mesh that I've created using meshgrid.

```
# get_field returns a single list [i,j,k] of the field vector evaluated at the input point [x,y,z]

# Create grid to evaluate field at points 
xx, yy, zz = np.meshgrid(np.arange(minX, maxX, spacing),
                     np.arange(minY, maxY, spacing),
                     np.arange(minZ, maxZ, spacing))

# Evaluate field at points
field = get_field([xx,yy,zz])

# Plot
ax.quiver(xx, yy, zz, field, length=1)
plt.show()
```

I'm having trouble mapping each directional vector `[i,j,k]` to a numpy array or list for plotting

**EDIT**
I fell back on brute forcing it.

```py
xx = np.arange(self.minX, self.maxX, spacing)
yy = np.arange(self.minY, self.maxY, spacing)
zz = np.arange(self.minZ, self.maxZ, spacing)

u = []
v = []
w = []

for x in xx:
     for y in yy:
          for z in zz:
                 # get_field returns a single list [i,j,k] of the field vector evaluated at the input point [x,y,z]
                 field = get_field([x, y, z])
                 u.append(field[0])
                 v.append(field[1])
                 w.append(field[2])
u = np.asarray(u)
v = np.asarray(v)
w = np.asarray(w)
plt_ax.quiver(xx, yy, zz, u, v, w, length=1, normalize=True)
```

I thought this implementation would at least work (badly), but now i'm receiving an error even though there are enough points to match the dimensions of xx,yy,zz.

```
ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape
```

Comment: Quiver plots arrows. Having x,y,z and field gives you a scalar field, but no vectors. Where do you want the arrows to point to in that case?

Comment: Because `get_field` outputs direction vectors `[x,y,z]` , I would like the arrows output from `get_field` to be mapped to their corresponding coordinate in the meshgrid.

Comment: Well, we have no idea about the output of `get_field`. [mcve].

Comment: I commented it above. The output for `get_field(P)` is a direction vector `[i,j,k]`, evaluated at point P, where P is a position `[X,Y,Z]`

Comment: You have one single vector? A quiver needs as many vectors as points of course. Or are they all equal? Anyways, please don't describe, but show!

Comment: Tried to brute force it in the meantime, but still having some trouble with quiver.